# Issue w/ Git push

Tags: git, gitlab

I try to make a push on my new 14th Ubuntu installation.
Here is the console output it face:

```
>     host@host:~/repo/cab$ git push origin master Counting objects: 46, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads. Compressing objects:
> 100% (9/9), done. Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 957 bytes | 0
> bytes/s, done. Total 13 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0) remote:
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92:in
> `block in materialize': Could not find rake-10.3.2 in any of the
> sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) remote:    from
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
> `map!' remote:    from
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in
> `materialize' remote:     from
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in
> `specs' remote:   from
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in
> `specs_for' remote:   from
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in
> `requested_specs' remote:     from
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in
> `requested_specs' remote:     from
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in
> `setup' remote:   from
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler.rb:121:in
> `setup' remote:   from
> /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in
> `<top (required)>' remote:    from
> /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require' remote:
>   from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
> To http://gitlab.loc/group/cab.git  ! [remote rejected] master ->
> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to
> 'http://gitlab.loc/group/cab.git'
```

This is Java project. There is no relation to Ruby at all.
What have I broken here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems that problem was from my side: i cloned my repo two month ago and didn't touch it since then till today. A couple of min. ago i cloned the same project into another location and now it seems that everything is fine. Thanx everyone for assist!

Answer (score 3):

> There is no relation to Ruby at all.

There is actually: you are pushing to [a GitLab server](https://about.gitlab.com/) (written in Ruby), and probably not with the right "project access" ([introduced in 2014](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/11/26/keeping-your-code-protected/)).
If `master` is protected, GitLab will reject the push.

That is what  `[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)` means.

See "[GitLab Permissions](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/permissions/permissions.html)": only a `master` or `owner` can push to a protected branch.

Here is what I see for the `pre-receive` hook set by GitLab:

```
[<gitlab-server>:/path/to/gitlab-shell/hooks] $ more pre-receive
```

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# This file was placed here by GitLab. It makes sure that your pushed commits
# will be processed properly.

refs = ARGF.read
key_id  = ENV['GL_ID']
repo_path = Dir.pwd

require_relative '../lib/gitlab_custom_hook'
require_relative '../lib/gitlab_access'

if GitlabAccess.new(repo_path, key_id, refs).exec &&
    GitlabCustomHook.new.pre_receive(refs, repo_path)
  exit 0
else
  # reset GL_ID env since we stop git push here
  ENV['GL_ID'] = nil

  exit 1
end
```

---

The OP adds:

> I cloned my repo two month ago and didn't touch it since then till today.
>   A couple of minutes ago, I cloned the same project into another location and now it seems that everything is fine.

The credentials associated with that new clone must be different from the ones used at the time in the first repo.

Comment: the problem is not in roles

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим yes it is (actually, the right term is "project access"): the pre-receive hook you mention in your answer is set by GitLab itself in order to enforce branch protection.

Comment: it can be anything it pre-receive hook

Comment: @СеменихинМаксим yes, except we are talking about a *GitLab* server. I am admin of my own GitLab server: that is how user roles (http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/permissions/README.html) are enforced.

Answer (score 1):

Look at those lines:

```
> To http://gitlab.loc/group/cab.git  ! [remote rejected] master ->
> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to
```

Pay attention to `remote rejected` and `pre-receive hook declined`

**It seem like your repository has a pre-receive hook and it declined you push**

[More about git hooks link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)

AS [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) pointed [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38179214/issue-w-git-push/38180004#answer-38179925) it can because of [GitLab roles](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/permissions/README.html)